# La etiqueta BR se guarda la siguiente forma <br />

Tags: html

Por que la etiqueta **br** se guarda de la siguiente formar `<br />` en lugar de `<br>` en **html**?

Comment: En HMTL no se hace. <br/> es xml.

Answer (score 2):

Se les considera [void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) por que no pueden tener ningún contenido (dado que no hay una etiqueta final, no se puede colocar contenido entre la etiqueta inicial y la etiqueta final).

Existen 6 tipos de elementos en resumen :

**Void elements**

```
 area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, link, meta, source, track, wbr
```

**The template element**

```
template
```

**Raw text elements**

```
script, style
```

**Escapable raw text elements**

```
textarea, title
```

**Foreign elements**

```
Elements from the MathML namespace and the SVG namespace.
```

**Normal elements**

```
All other allowed HTML elements are normal elements.
```

En este [link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html) esta a detalle la explicación de la sintaxis HTML.

Comment: Bien visto, en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Void_element) lo explican en español.  Y en este [otro enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#the_curious_case_of_self-closing_tags) (en inglés) dan un poco más de explicación sobre la barra de cierre.